# Google map fails to load after initiail page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
I've put a google map on a static page in my rails app. Upon initial load the map is fine but I don't know the right javascript to make it load on subsequent page loadings.

The code responsible:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.619885, -0.523137);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Welcome!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I disabled turbolinks and it works now. As it's a simple site performance hasn't suffered. Is there a downside to disabling turbolinks?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This should refresh the map

Comment: Sorry, no luck. I've posted the whole thing now.

Comment: Just a comment. You should get an API key for Google maps, or it might not work properly. When you do your new source it will be `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>`